# Packaging an Angular service in an external library?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If we want to create a service in an external library that we will install in other projects as a dependency how do we annotate the service?

Do we use use:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
}
)
```

Without adding a module configuration to go with it.  What if we want the library's service to be registered in a lazy loaded module.  How should that type of service be annotated and declared in the module loading the service?

Comment: Would you like it as singleton?

Comment: Yes - Singleton Good!

Comment: So I just tested packaging a service using `@injectable({providedIn: 'root'}), without any additional module configuration for the library, and it seems to be working fine, so perhaps it's that simple ...

Comment: use ModuleWithProviders for sharedModule and define forRoot and forChild option as RouterModule defines it to avoid multiple instance issue with lazily loaded modules

Answer (score 1):

For root loaded modules these are the steps

```
ng new my-workspace --create-application=false
cd my-workspace

ng generate library my-lib
```

Remove everything except for `my-lib.service.ts`.

And make sure to update `public-api.ts` so that it only exports the service:

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of my-lib
 */
export * from './lib/my-lib.service';
```

Then build the library and install it into other angular projects.  Angular will dependency inject the service when it is declared in the constructor of directives.

I'm still curious how to go about registering the service in lazy loaded modules consuming the library and how should the service be annotated in these cases?